# Sharing code between ASP.NET MVC 5, ASP.NET Web Api 2 and Mobile (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, .net-standard

I'm an experienced ASP.NET MVC and Web Api 2 Developer and now our company is starting on mobile development.

Our projects use .net framework 4.7.2.

We have a "common library" that all our projects reference.

Also, we have a POCO class project, which, of course, contains only poco classes (we use entity framework 6)

So, what we need is to use that "common library" and the POCO classes with the mobile software, while using them on existing projects, like the ASP.NET MVC 5 project.

What is necessary to accomplish it, considering we do not want to "duplicate" code?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Convert that net framework 4.7.2 common library to a .NetStd2 library

Comment: It _depends_ on the app. You stated you have a Web API, would that satisfy the need/s of your mobile app (essentially a "dumb termnal" calling your web api)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Shared Projects.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/code-sharing#Shared_Projects)

[Here is a complete walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows) how to achieve that (the tutorial is long so I won't post any steps).

With this, you can reference the models in other projects, and keep the always updated.